# Finding the probability of choosing six numbers

Tags: probability

I just started to learn probability and came across this question:

> Six numbers are selected without replacement from the list {2, 3, 7, 8, 12, 15, 17, 21, 28}. Find the probability that the third largest number is 15.

I know that I need to use combinations but I don't know in what way. Also, there are 3 numbers greater than 15. Does this piece of information help me in any way? Any help or hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to find the probability of choosing two of the three numbers larger than 15, choosing 15, and choosing any other three numbers.

Comment: Hint: Count the ways to select the number `15`, 2 of the 3 numbers greater than it, and 3 of the 5 numbers less than it.

Answer (score 2):

If 15 is the third largest number, then it follows that there must be 2 numbers larger than it, and 3 numbers smaller than it.

As you said, there are 3 numbers greater than 15- 17, 21 and 28. We must choose 2 of these. This can be done in $\binom{3}{2}=3$ ways.

If there are 3 numbers smaller than it, we must simply select 3 numbers from the set {2,3,7,8,12}. This can be done in $\binom{5}{3}=10$ ways.

Total possible selections= $\binom{9}{6}=84$.

So the probability is: $\frac{3*10}{84}=\frac{5}{14}$.

Comment: I get it now! However, wouldn't it be more clear if we included $C_1,1$ because we still need to pick 15?

Comment: 15 is guaranteed to be picked. Or you can think about it as $\binom{1}{1}=1$, because there is only 1 way that you can pick it, so there's no real need to include it.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Na/N

where Na is the number of possible ways to select your required numbers and n is the total of ways you can choose any 6 of the nine available numbers.

Na = Combin. 3 choose 2 (for two of the three numbers larger than 15) * Combin. 1 choose 1 (this is the selection of 15) * Combin. 5 choose 3 (this is you selecting any three of the 5 numbers smaller than 15)

N= Combin. 9 choose 6. (which is $9!/6!3!$)

Your answer is given by $Na/N$ which is 3*1*10/84 = 30/84 = 15/42

Remember you find combinations with n!/r!(n-r)! where n,r come from nCr.

Hope that helps.